# Magento Collection Query

Tags: magento, collections

I created new customer attribute 'personal_number' and now want to show it in new column in adminhtml sales_order_grid.
I've done all stuff to show column in grid (class rewrite in config.xml), created MyName_MyModule_Block_Adminhtml_Order_Grid where need to rewrite _getCollectionClass() and _prepareColumns(). My problem is in _getCollectionClass() where I need to do database query to join customers attribute data to orders collection. Becouse I'am very new in Magento, logic of magento-way queries for me is very hard to follow. Can someone help me to write MySql query below in Magento-way to get value of my customer attribute 'personal_number' in orders grid:

```
SELECT Orders.*, Customers.customer_id, Custumer.personal_namber FROM Orders INNER JOIN Customers ON Orders.customer_id = Customer.customer_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You usually don't need to change `_getCollectionClass`, but rather do the join on the grid, on `_prepareCollection`. Ie:

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());

    //we changed mysql query, we added inner join to order item table
    $collection->join(
    // Alias => Table name
    array('customers' => "customer/customer"), 
    // Join condition
    'main_table.customer_id = customer.customer_id', 
    // Fields to select
    array('personal_number'=>'personal_number');
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

Taken from here, have a look at the full article for more help: http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-extend-magento-order-grid/

Comment: it was my copy/paste error... I ment _prepareCollection()... But I can not figure out how to write $collection->join('some_query') for INNER JOIN Customers ON Orders.customer_id = Customer.customer_id to get my custom attribute value personal_number

Comment: Edited the answer with the join for customer table and added some comments, hopefully it works or helps you to get the solution.